# Camera preview doesn't show on first load on Android

Tags: android, cordova, camera, android-camera, cordova-plugins

Cordova app, using camera plugin https://github.com/mbppower/CordovaCameraPreview

I start up the camera service, hide it, then when the user hits a specific page show the preview window again. It works perfectly on iOS, but not Android. When running it on an Android device the camera preview window is not shown by default, but it does appear if I minimize (by hitting the home button) and then re-opening the app.

I have added a console.log to the show method and it is indeed being called even though the preview window doesn't show.

Main init method:

```
        var onDeviceReady = function () {

            var tapEnabled = false; //enable tap take picture
            var dragEnabled = false; //enable preview box drag across the screen
            var toBack = false; //send preview box to the back of the webview

            var rect = {x: 428, y: 190, width: 200, height: 150};

            cordova.plugins.camerapreview.startCamera(rect, "front", tapEnabled, dragEnabled, toBack);
            cordova.plugins.camerapreview.hide();
        };
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

My show and hide functions:

```
    var _show = function () {
        // Show camera preview
        if(cordova) {
            console.log("show camera");
            $timeout(function () {
                cordova.plugins.camerapreview.show();
            }, 250);
        }
    };

    var _hide = function () {
        // Hide camera preview
        if(cordova) {
            $timeout(function () {
                cordova.plugins.camerapreview.hide();
            }, 0);
        }
    };
```

1. Even after show() function is called, camera preview does not display on first load. I must minimize then open the app again for preview to display. Why does it work fine in iOS but misbehaves like this on Android?

**Update**

If I never hide it (remove the .hide() call when I start the camera) then it shows up perfectly fine! The issue arises if I hide it then try to reshow. It'll only show up once I minimize then reopen the app. To make it even stranger; if inside of the onDeviceReady above I call .hide() and then .show() right away it shows the preview window!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed the problem but I don't understand it and would love some feedback.

Instead of the camerapreview.hide() call in my onDeviceReady, I call my private function _hide() outside* of the onDeviceReady. I thought to try this because calling .hide then .show shows the preview window, but calling .hide .show then .hide again presents the same defect.

```
var _hide = function () {
    // Hide camera preview
    if(cordova) {
        $timeout(function () {
            cordova.plugins.camerapreview.hide();
        }, 0);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and fixed it by calling the `.hide()` method in the callback of `.startCamera()` returned promise.

```
this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraOptions).then(() => {
   this.camera.hide();
});
```

This way camera preview will hide only when it is fully initialized. and you can open camera at any point later in the app by using `this.cameraPreview.show()` method.